# Selecting unique column position of a non-zero value for each row of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix in this case of 3x11, but I want this to work for any dimension matrix. I want per row a column position on a non-zero value in that row, but that this value should be different than a column position already selected for another row. 
I also tried to solve it with a set of three lists and tried to get a sample from each list.

For example:

```
m = {{1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

A result would be {8,9,11} Even though position 8 is non-zero in the first and the second row/list, this position can be selected as long as a different position is chosen for the second row/list.

Preferentially the last positions (with the higher numbers) should be selected.

Answer (score 5):

We construct an edge list from `m` using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and use [`FindIndependentEdgeSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html) to get the desired result.

For the  *"preferentially the last positions (with the higher numbers) should be selected"* part, for each edge `v1 -> v2` we use `v2` as the edge weight.

```
ClearAll[edges]
edges[m_] := DirectedEdge[{a, #[[1]]}, {b, #[[2]]}] & /@ SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"];
FindIndependentEdgeSet[edges[m], EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> e[[-1, -1]]}][[All, -1, -1]]
```

> {8, 9, 11}

To make the last positions as small as possible we can use `1 / v2` as the edge weight for edge `v1 -> v2`:

```
FindIndependentEdgeSet[edges[m], EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> 1 / e[[-1, -1]]}][[All, -1, -1]]
```

> {1, 7, 10}

An alternative approach is to use constrained optimization:

```
indices = SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"];
vars = xx @@@ indices;
objective = vars.(Last /@ vars);
constraints = Join[Thread[0 <= vars <= 1], 
     Values@GroupBy[vars, First, Total[#] == 1 &], 
     Values@GroupBy[vars, Last, 0 <= Total[#] <= 1 &]];
argmax = ArgMax[{objective, constraints}, vars];
Pick[indices, argmax, 1]
```

> {{1, 9}, {2, 8}, {3, 11}}

Change `ArgMax` to `ArgMin` to make the second positions as small as possible:

```
argmin = ArgMin[{objective, constraints}, vars];
Pick[indices, argmin, 1]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 7}, {3, 10}}

Comment: Thanks! It works :)

Comment: @Alice, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: `MaximalBy[#, Total]&` seems to work as well in place of `Internal`ListMin`.

Comment: @Anjan, great idea; thank you.